# is flux.interval not eager not lazy

Tags: java, reactive-programming

`Publisher` generates value could be categorized as lazy and eager, like `Mono.just` and `Flux.fromIterable` are eager, and http operations are lazy since they only emit value when `block` or `subscirbe` is called. But I happen to find that based on this division, `Flux.interval` does not belong to either:

```
@Test
public void interval() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux<Long> delay = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).log(); // t0
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); // t0+2
    Flux<Long> longFlux = Flux.just(0, 0, 0).zipWith(delay, (a, b) -> a + b).log(); // t0+2+5
    StepVerifier.create(longFlux).expectNext(0l,1l,2l).verifyComplete();
}
```

If it is eager, it should be t0+5, if it is lazy, it should wait for `subscribe` or `block` being called.